# Setting correct coordinate system when rxporting from Draftsight

Tags: qgis, dxf

I'm trying to import a DXF into GIS (I have QGIS, Arcmap 9.2, GVsig )
The file has been given a coordinate system & appears to be the right size, just in the wrong place.
In Draftsight (or any other software that can read DXF) how can I set a correct coordinate system?  I've been looking at the Draftsight resources but can't work it out as I have limited CAD knowledge.

I can't really affine this in QGIS as I have no base mapping, but I am sure I know the existing CS is out by 400,000m on x & 100,000 on y (OSGB Tile code SU) so if I could do this in Draftsight & re-save it it would come out correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a hamfisted way to do it, but I managed it through:
Select All > Move.  I selected the from point with esnap then entered the destination point from the cmd line, adding a leading 4 & 1 to the coordinates.
Now in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the DraftSight Documentation, the tool uses a Cartesian coordinate system (CCS) which consiss of three coordinate axes. As you have already posted an answer on a possible method, you can find more information about setting up a coordinate system in the following links from the documentation:

- [Specifying Coordinates and Using Coordinate Systems](http://www.aem-e.com/draftsight/html/coordinate_systems.htm)
- [Managing Custom Coordinate Systems](http://www.aem-e.com/draftsight/html/hlpid_adjust_ucsman.htm)
- [Setting Up Custom Coordinate Systems](http://www.aem-e.com/draftsight/html/hlpid_adjust_ucs.htm)

Comment: Thanks Joseph - I had looked at these and they didn't convey much to me: when I tried to define a CCS it asked about the origin & x plane & lost me there - I couldn't specify a new origin as I had no backdrop to get one from & not at all sure about the x plane...  Then it struck me that actually the coordinate system was OK & the data in the wrong place.  I'm gradually trying to get to grips with CAD but it's a different way of thinking to GIS & that's what I was brought up on. I'll revisit the documentation when I've got this deadline over. Cheers.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, there's nothing like having an Einstein moment where you find an answer yourself and not from the dozens of sources you had to trawl through!